# Rails 3 render :partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I am migrating my 1.8.7 rails app to rails 3. But I have a problem with a partial:
I have the following partial:

in my cms controller :

`@clients = Client.all 

group = render_to_string :layout => 'layouts/window', :partial => 'clients/index'`

in my "clients/index" partial:

`<%= render :partial => 'clients/item', :collection => @clients %>`

This worked great with rails 1.7.8 but with rails 3 only the partial in the index get's rendered!. So, to clarify this, the group variable in the controller doesn't get the html from the layout. 
Also the weird thing is that the window layout is _window.erb  (if I do window.html.erb or just window.erb rails can't find it which is strange).

Does anybody know if this behavior is normal for rails 3?

thanxs!

Comment: Rails 1.7.8? Did you mean 2.3.8? What version of Rails 3 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Partials in rails have to start with underscore. Try renaming your "item.html.erb" partial to "_item.html.erb".